How can I efficiently find triplets in an array where the difference of two elements equals the third element?
I'm working on a problem where I need to preprocess an array to determine the number of divisors for each element, resulting in an array $f$. The goal is to find three elements in the $f$ array such that the sum of two elements equals the third, while ensuring the indices satisfy $1 \leq i < j < k \leq n$.

Problem Statement:
Dan defines $f(x)$ as the number of divisors of a number $x$. For example, $f(6) = 4$ (the divisors of 6 are 1, 2, 3, and 6).
We consider a triplet $(i, j, k)$ (where $1 \leq i < j < k \leq n$) as a "perfect triplet" if it satisfies: $f(a_i) - f(a_j) = f(a_k)$.
Given an array $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$ of length $n$, Dan wants to know how many different perfect triplets exist.
Two triplets are considered different if at least one of their indices differs. For example, $(1, 2, 3)$ and $(1, 2, 4)$ are two distinct triplets.
Input Description:

The first line contains an integer $n$ $(3 \leq n \leq 10^5)$ representing the length of the array.
The second line contains $n$ integers $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$ $(1 \leq a_i \leq 10^6)$ representing the elements of the array.

Output Description:

Output a single integer representing the number of perfect triplets.


My Thought Process:

I initially considered preprocessing the divisor counts into the $f$ array, which is straightforward. The challenge then becomes finding triplets $(f[i], f[j], f[k])$ such that $f[i] + f[j] = f[k]$, with the indices satisfying $i < j < k$.

My initial approach involved checking every possible triplet, which naturally led to an $O(n^3)$ solution, so I explored optimizations.

I am now stuck trying to further optimize this solution. All my approaches still seem to involve a nested loop or some variant, keeping the complexity at $O(n^2)$.


Is there a more efficient way to solve this problem, ideally one that reduces the time complexity below $O(n^2)$ while respecting the index constraints?

The Problem Statement says f(a_i) - f(a_j) , not f(a_i) + f(a_j). Please fix your title and text accordingly.

@nocomment You can derive the meaning expressed in the problem by simply rearranging the equation. It’s essentially about finding the sum of two numbers such that this sum is also present in the array, and its index is smaller than the indices of the two numbers.

You could do that, but at least your "$f[i] + f[j] = f[k]$, with the indices satisfying $i < j < k$" doesn't. It would have to say "$f[i] = f[j] + f[k]$". But I'd say better don't rearrange it, stick with the task as given, with difference, not sum. There's nothing wrong with it, and it's needlessly confusing to have your text differ from the given text.

Ugh. Please don't change the original given specification. Now my answer looks like I was hallucinating, talking about differences. And the disagreement between that text and yours is still there.

(Then again, sum can be turned difference as you move one of the variables to the other side)


Sort the array.
Use two left and right pointers (lo, hi).
Loop through the array once:
While lo is smaller than the hi: (a) calculate the total sum of three numbers
If total sum was negative, move the left pointer.
If total sum was positive, move the right pointer.
If total sum was equal to zero, we have a triplet.

def find_triplets(nums):
    triplets = []
    nums.sort()

    for i in range(len(nums) - 2):
        if i > 0 and nums[i] == nums[i - 1]:
            continue

        lo, hi = i + 1, len(nums) - 1

        while lo < hi:
            total = nums[i] + nums[lo] + nums[hi]

            if total < 0:
                lo += 1
            elif total > 0:
                hi -= 1
            else:
                triplets.append([nums[i], nums[lo], nums[hi]])

                while lo < hi and nums[lo] == nums[lo + 1]:
                    lo += 1
                while lo < hi and nums[hi] == nums[hi - 1]:
                    hi -= 1

                lo += 1
                hi -= 1

    return triplets


print(find_triplets([-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, 10, 11, 12, -4, -12, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7, -4, -6, 13]))

which prints:

[[-12, -1, 13], [-12, 0, 12], [-12, 1, 11], [-12, 2, 10], [-12, 3, 9],
[-12, 5, 7], [-6, -4, 10], [-6, -1, 7], [-6, 0, 6], [-6, 1, 5], [-6,
3, 3], [-4, -4, 8], [-4, -1, 5], [-4, 1, 3], [-1, -1, 2], [-1, 0, 1]]


I initially considered your approach, which involves a loop with nested two pointers. However, there are two drawbacks with this method:

The problem allows $n$ to reach up to $10^5$, and using this approach would lead to a time complexity of $O(n^2)$, which will definitely result in a timeout.
You're calculating the sum of three elements, but the problem does not involve sums. Since $i$, $j$, and $k$ do not satisfy rotational symmetry, you cannot sort the array in advance.


@korangarleo I see.

You want to count how often each element occurred as the difference of two previous elements. So keep track of how often each difference occurred so you can look that up. To do that, also keep track of how often each value occurred (f is the array of f-values):
def fast(f):
    result = 0
    vals = Counter()
    diffs = Counter()
    for x in f:
        result += diffs[x]
        for v in vals:
            diffs[v-x] += vals[v]
        vals[x] += 1
    return result

My inner loop for v in vals: is relatively short, as there are only 94 possible f-values (hardcoded in my below test data generator). Could be further reduced like for v in minuends[x]:, looking up and going through only those values v such that v-x is a possible f-value. But my code already only takes a few seconds for n=10^5, and that's with Python (which is relatively slow).
Testing script sample output showing results and times (in seconds) for n=500:
73077 naive 4.634257793426514
73077 fast 0.02181863784790039

Testing script:
import random
from collections import Counter
from time import time

n = 500
f = random.choices([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 30, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 38, 39, 40, 42, 44, 45, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 54, 55, 56, 60, 63, 64, 65, 66, 68, 70, 72, 75, 77, 78, 80, 81, 84, 88, 90, 96, 98, 99, 100, 104, 105, 108, 110, 112, 117, 120, 125, 126, 128, 132, 135, 140, 144, 150, 160, 162, 168, 176, 180, 189, 192, 200, 210, 216, 224, 240], k=n)

def naive(f):
    return sum(
        f[i] - f[j] == f[k]
        for k in range(len(f))
        for j in range(k)
        for i in range(j)
    )

def fast(f):
    result = 0
    vals = Counter()
    diffs = Counter()
    for x in f:
        result += diffs[x]
        for v in vals:
            diffs[v-x] += vals[v]
        vals[x] += 1
    return result

for func in naive, fast:
    t = time()
    print(func(f), func.__name__, time() - t)

Attempt This Online!

Can you explain why there are only 94 possible f-values?

@gimix Because they're numbers of divisors of numbers in 1..1000000. The number of divisors of a number is much smaller than the number. Have a look at Wikipedia's article Highly composite number. In the table you can see that 720720 has 240 divisors, the most of any number up to 1000000. You can also see 240 at the end of my list. And not all numbers of divisors appear in that range. You can see in my list that 23 is missing. It's prime, so the smallest number with exactly 23 divisors is 2^22, which is larger than 1000000.
